# accessing methods of page when accessing page with a page method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code behind file of an aspx file that looks like this:

```
public partial class Pages_MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     .....
  }

  protected int MyMethod()
  {
     .....
  }

  [WebMethod]
  public static int MyPageMethod()
  {
    int x = MyMethod();
    return x;
  }

}
```

When I'm sending an ajax POST to MyPageMethod, I can't access MyMethod. What's the way around this issue.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMethods are `static` methods because they don't get a full `Page`.

They can only call other `static` methods

Answer (score 2):

`MyMethod` will also need to be static.

Think about what your trying to do here -

`MyMethod` belongs to a specific *instance* of a *class*.

`MyPageMethod` belongs to the *class* itself.

If your running code inside `MyPageMethod`, how could you possibly know how to call methods on some other instance of the object. The *instance* methods may as well not exist at that point in code.

If you are trying to mutate some portion of the page's data from *javascript*, you have a deep misunderstanding of how *asp.net* pages work.

At the point *javascript* is running in the browser, your page object is gone. The server finished the page load and discarded it. On the next *post back* it will create a new instance, and run through the page life cycle once again.

If you need to access page level state, you will have to store it in a place that is acceptable between post backs, the Session object for instance, with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`

Comment: Thanks; I'm not mutating the page from javascript, I'm just writing an ajax call back. I'll add he static keyword to make it work.

Comment: The fact is that PageMethods, being static, bypass the page lifecycle completely. There really isn't any page lifecycle because an instance of the Page class is never created.